# Расчет полей формы Django

Tags: django

Есть задача добавить в отображаемую форму автоматический расчет полей, чтобы при вводе значений в одно поле формы автоматически рассчитывалось другое. Например, как в гугл переводчике. Сейчас реализую это следующим образом:

```
class DealForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Deal

    fields = ['buy_price','percent','sell_price']

    widgets = {
        'buy_price':  forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'percent':  forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','onchange':'calcSell()'}),
        'sell_price':  forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
    }
```

Шаблон

```
<script>
function calcSell(){
var val1 = document.getElementById('id_buy_price').value
var val2 = document.getElementById('id_percent').value
var val3 = parseFloat(val1)*parseFloat(val2)
document.getElementById('id_sell_price').value = val3.toFixed(8)
}
</script>
```

Но в связи с тем, что расчетов должно быть значительно больше, то использование скриптов видится не лучшим решением. Однако "на лету" делать это варианта я не нашел пока. Вероятно, есть какой-либо общепринятый и более правильный способ реализации данного функционала.

Comment: Уже много лет как общепринятый и более правильный способ - не использовать событийные атрибуты, типа `onchange`. Ну и разумно максимально снизить связанность фронтенда и бэкенда.

Comment: Благодарю. Вот поэтому и спрашиваю, как это правильнее реализовать.

Comment: Вы уверены, что хотите позволить пользователю самому менять процент скидки?

Comment: В данном случае это не имеет значения. Важен сам механизм реализации, как правильно сделать расчет одного поля при введении данных в другое.

Comment: @RyndinV если через сервер, то только через отправку ajax-запроса при срабатывании события input. Хотел бы понять вашу фразу про "использование скриптов видится не лучшим решением". Почему не лу, шим?

Comment: В форме будет порядка 5 полей, которые нужно будет рассчитывать и от изменения одного поля будет зависеть значение нескольких других. Делать такое через JS и считать на стороне клиента разве гуд?